# Masonry.js And Floated Div Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

I'm using masonry.js quite a lot in a new website that I'm developing but there is one flaw with using it in my design when it comes to floating my columns side by side. Here is a general representation of what I'm trying to do:

Normal View:

```
[ column left ] [ main column                  ] [[masonry post]] [ column right ]
[             ] [                              ] [[masonry post]] [              ]
[             ] [                              ] [[masonry post]] [              ]
[             ] [                              ] [[masonry post]] [              ]
[             ] [                              ] [[masonry post]] [              ]
```

Responsive view:

```
[ column left ] [ main column                  ] [ column right ]
[             ] [                              ] [              ]
[             ] [                              ] [              ]
[             ] [ [masonry post][masonry post] ] [              ]
[             ] [ [masonry post][masonry post] ] [              ]
[             ] [ [masonry post][masonry post] ] [              ]
```

So the "main column" and "masonry post" columns are floated left so that when the browser is shrunk down, the masonry column goes beneath the main column, which in theory works perfectly, however because Masonry JS is applied to the masonry column it doesn't move like it's supposed to - Instead, it stays where it is and gets hidden behind the right hand column. Any ideas on how this can be sorted?

Comment: From whatever information you've provided I would suggest using media query to alter width of the masonry container to switch the responsive view. 

Can you post some code? Preferably a jsFiddle!